# How could this edit be rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I edited this answer today: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13224483

In it there is actually a typo ("Sata" should be "Data") and "Foreground color" should be quoted. Nothing important but it's better after my edit. However it was rejected saying that it's not more accurate or easier to read, which is not true.

I would like that answer corrected for other users that may read it. So how should I edit it so that it's not rejected?

Comment: Please ask this question on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) as it pertains to Stack Overflow only, not the entire Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @Glorfindel not really, this can be seen as general question "why minor edit rejected"

Answer (score 4):

Only the reviewers know for sure why they rejected, but I can venture a guess.

The edit does have a few good points, the quoting of "Foreground color" and the fixing of the typo.

However, you also changed every "->" into ">". It is a matter of style, but when describing which path to follow in a menu, I for one prefer "->". And I think many people prefer that.

Your edit summary says "fixed typo and style". The reviewers probably didn't agree with the style change.

My advice is to not change more style than is necessary. Do, however, continue to fix typos.

Answer (score 2):

The typo fix was the only "real" edit. Changing "->" to ">" is too minor, and indeed fits perfectly for "does not make the post even a little bit easier to read".

The typo fix justifies an edit, so I assume the three who rejected missed that, as it was hidden by the other edits you made. (Took me a while to see you replaced "Sata" with "Data")

All in all, it should be approved, but I can understand why it didn't. I fixed the typo now, in the future just keep in mind such minor edits might be rejected.

Comment: Putting "Foreground color" between double-quotes was also OK, as it made that styling consistent. It really is more legible with that phrase between double-quotes.

Comment: @S.L.Barth thanks, missed that. Edited now. :)

Comment: @nicael lol, I meant that I edited the answer on SO, not this answer. No magic here. ;-)